# Universal solution to insert Userinput values in MySQL database with a priori unknown columns with Java and for example PreparedStatements

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, sql-insert

I want to insert a whole set of values in my table in MySQL
(e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE Flughafen (
    Abkuerzung VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    Zeitzone INT,
    Standort VARCHAR(255),
    Name VARCHAR(255),
    Flughafensteuer DOUBLE,
    Sicherheitsgebuehren DOUBLE,
    PRIMARY KEY (Abkuerzung)
);
INSERT INTO Flughafen VALUES ("AMK", 69, "Germany", "Munich", 30, 50);
```

This works in MySQL Workbench 8.0 but not in my Java Code.
I read the JavaDoc about prepared Statements but I didn't find any clues on inserting values if I don't know the type a priori. My Java code looks like this:

```
            // Laden des JDBC-Treiber für MySQL
            String driverClass = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/wwfsaew";
            String username = "root";
            try {
                //Laden des Treibers fuer Java und MySQL
                Class.forName(driverClass);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException exc) {
                System.out.println("Treiber fehlt");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            try {
                // Aufbau der Verbindung
                connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
                System.out.println("------------ SQL Befehl wird verschickt ---------------");
            } catch (SQLException SQLe) {
                System.out.println("Verbinden fehlgeschlagen bitte noch einmal probieren!");
                SQLe.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(5);
            }
            //Erlaubnis fuer Abfragen an die Datenbank
            statement = connect.createStatement();
            //Vorabfrage der Tabelle für spätere Eingabe des Benutzers
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Tabelle);
            System.out.println("--- DatenbankZugriff wird initiiert ---");

            String Insertabfrage = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(1);
            String Fragezeichen = "?";
            for (int i = 2; i<= resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                Insertabfrage += (", " + resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(i));
                Fragezeichen += ",?";
            }

            System.out.println(Insertabfrage);
            System.out.println("Werte bitte in richtiger Ordnung eingeben und Werte : ");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String SQLInsert = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(SQLInsert);


----------------------------------------------------------------

Here I want to handle the Statement and insert it into my database.

String sql = "INSERT INTO " + Tabelle + " (" + Insertabfrage + ") VALUES ("
                    + " values (" + Fragezeichen + ")";
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(sql);

----------------------------------------------------------------

            resultSet = statement.executeQuery("INSERT INTO " + Tabelle + " (" + Insertabfrage + ") VALUES ("  + SQLInsert + " );");
            //Ausgaben der Abfrage antworten mit Meta Daten
            System.out.println("--- SQL Befehl wurde erfolgreich umgesetzt! ---");
```

I tried many things like
`resultSet = statement.executeQuery("INSERT INTO " + Tabelle + " (" + Insertabfrage + ") VALUES ("  + SQLInsert + " );");`
So my Question is, is there a possibility to get the Datatype of the columns and insert it into my database wwfsaew? Something like this:

```
preparedStatement.setUniversal(1, InputString(1));
preparedStatement.setUniversal(2, InputString(2));
preparedStatement.setUniversal(3, InputString(3));
```

Comment: `for(int i = 0;i<resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++)preparedStatement.setObject(i, SQLInsert[i], resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnType(i));`

Comment: Any error? Do you have transactions?

Comment: Sorry, but commenting is new for me :D
The problem is it doesn't insert it into the database.
If I add e.g. 
```
String[] SQLI = SQLInsert.split(Pattern.quote(","));
for(int i = 1;i<resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                preparedStatement.setObject(i, SQLI[i], resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnType(i));
            }
```
```
BAT,69,Turkey,Batman,30,50;
```

Comment: It doesn't throw an error

Comment: For-loop should start at 0 and `preparedStatement.setObject(i+1, SQLI[i], resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnType(i));`. SQLi and `getColumnType` are 0 based

Comment: Then it throws: Column index out of range.

Comment: my bad, only `SQLi` is 0 based. `preparedStatement.setObject(i+1, SQLI[i], resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnType(i+1));` for 0 based for-loop or `preparedStatement.setObject(i, SQLI[i-1], resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnType(i));` if for loop starts at 1

Comment: Ok, I wrote it like your Code, it compiles and runs correctly but still, there is no new row in Flughafen. SELECT * FROM Flughafen; Does not show the new values in MySQL Workbench 8.0.

Comment: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''AMK',69,'Germany','Munich',30.0,50.0)' at line 1
That is the Exception thrown after preparedStatement.execute();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problems:

1. String sql was flawed --> double values().
2. There wasn't an execute command for preparedStatement
3. for loop from XtremeBaumer in the comments
4. ExceptionHandling for Foreign Keys
   I hope this helps somebody in the future :)